# How to print directly to the default printer Windows Store App C#?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm developing a Windows Store app in C# that is a self service totem to run in a hospital. When the patient touches a button in the screen, a kind of receipt should be printed. The question is: How to print this receipt directly to the default printer without any more user interactions?

Comment: Create a PrintDocument object and use the default settings.

Comment: In a store app, all printing goes through the Charms Bar, you can initiate it through your app. Take a look at this [MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Print-Sample-c544cce6/sourcecode?fileId=43921&pathId=1713588077) Print Sample. expecially scenario 2